# Change view without "back" button Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some button in this way, using Ionic and AngularJS:

```
<li menu-close class="item item-icon-left sider itemCustomColor" ng-click="go('#/app/contactus')">                    
                    <i class="icon ion-home"></i> Home
</li>
```

Where go method is in my controller:

```
$scope.go = function (url) {
        try {
            $location.path(url);
        } catch(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```

It is working in someway, when I am in some page and then I move to other by the button it displays:

[image]

As you can see there is a "back" button to the before page, I want just keep desplaying as it was before, for example:

[image]

I just can simulate that behaviour when I put it in a `<a href="#link">` tag, I have some specific topics (is another history) and I would like to achieve it in my controller.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

add `hide-back-button="true"` to your ion-view tag.

To display what you had before you can add the following before your ion-content:

`<ion-nav-buttons side="left"> //Add the code for your item here
</ion-nav-buttons>`